# Linq Left Outer Join with Count

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I want to create this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    a.[Seat], 
    b.[PlayerId], 
    b.[UserName], 
    b.[NickName],
    COUNT(c.PlayerId) AS Trophy
    FROM   [dbo].[tbl_PlayerTableSeat] AS a
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Player] AS b ON a.[PlayerId] = b.[PlayerId]               
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_GameVirtualTable] AS d ON d.GameVirtualTableId = a.GameVirtualTableId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_PlayerTableWinning] AS c ON a.[PlayerId] = c.[PlayerId] AND c.GameTableId = d.GameTableId                
    WHERE a.GameVirtualTableId = 36
    GROUP BY a.[Seat], b.[PlayerId], b.[UserName], b.[NickName]
```

I have this Linq

```
var virtualTableSeatList = (from s in db.PlayerTableSeat
                        join p in db.Player on s.PlayerId equals p.PlayerId
                        join v in db.GameVirtualTable on s.GameVirtualTableId equals v.GameVirtualTableId
                        join w in db.PlayerTableWinning on new { X1 = s.PlayerId, X2 = v.GameTableId } equals new { X1 = w.PlayerId, X2 = w.GameTableId } into gj

                        from g in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where s.GameVirtualTableId == virtualGameTableId
                        group new { p, s } by new { p.PlayerId, s.Seat, p.NickName, p.UserName } into grp

                        select new VirtualTableSeatDto
                        {
                            PlayerId = grp.Key.PlayerId,
                            Seat = grp.Key.Seat,
                            NickName = grp.Key.NickName,
                            UserName = grp.Key.UserName,                                            
                            Trophy = grp.Count()
                        }
               ).ToList();
```

From SQL Profiler, the Linq generates this SQL query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[K2] AS [PlayerId], 
 CAST( [GroupBy1].[K1] AS int) AS [C1], 
[GroupBy1].[K4] AS [NickName], 
[GroupBy1].[K3] AS [UserName], 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Seat] AS [K1], 
    [Extent2].[PlayerId] AS [K2], 
    [Extent2].[UserName] AS [K3], 
    [Extent2].[NickName] AS [K4], 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM    [dbo].[tbl_PlayerTableSeat] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Player] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PlayerId] = [Extent2].[PlayerId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_GameVirtualTable] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[GameVirtualTableId] = [Extent3].[GameVirtualTableId]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_PlayerTableWinning] AS [Extent4] ON ([Extent1].[PlayerId] = [Extent4].[PlayerId]) AND ([Extent3].[GameTableId] = [Extent4].[GameTableId])
    WHERE [Extent1].[GameVirtualTableId] = @p__linq__0
    GROUP BY [Extent1].[Seat], [Extent2].[PlayerId], [Extent2].[UserName], [Extent2].[NickName]
)  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=36
```

I want to change `COUNT(1) AS [A1]` to `COUNT([Extent4].[PlayerId]) AS [A1]`

so it can return correct data. 
I have no idea how to change the LinQ

`Trophy = grp.Count()`

so that it can count `PlayerId` of `PlayerTableWinning` instead of COUNT(1)

---

Updated: @Ivan Stoev

By adding the g into the group.

```
group new { p, s, g }
```

And sum the group

```
Trophy = grp.Sum(item => item.w != null ? 1 : 0)
```

It return the correct answer. However, it is using SUM instead of count. The SQL query generated is as below:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[K2] AS [PlayerId], 
 CAST( [GroupBy1].[K1] AS int) AS [C1], 
[GroupBy1].[K4] AS [NickName], 
[GroupBy1].[K3] AS [UserName], 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Filter1].[K1] AS [K1], 
    [Filter1].[K2] AS [K2], 
    [Filter1].[K3] AS [K3], 
    [Filter1].[K4] AS [K4], 
    SUM([Filter1].[A1]) AS [A1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Seat] AS [K1], 
        [Extent2].[PlayerId] AS [K2], 
        [Extent2].[UserName] AS [K3], 
        [Extent2].[NickName] AS [K4], 
        CASE WHEN ( NOT (([Extent4].[GameTableId] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[PlayerId] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[GameRoundId] IS NULL))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [A1]
        FROM    [dbo].[tbl_PlayerTableSeat] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Player] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PlayerId] = [Extent2].[PlayerId]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_GameVirtualTable] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[GameVirtualTableId] = [Extent3].[GameVirtualTableId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_PlayerTableWinning] AS [Extent4] ON ([Extent1].[PlayerId] = [Extent4].[PlayerId]) AND ([Extent3].[GameTableId] = [Extent4].[GameTableId])
        WHERE [Extent1].[GameVirtualTableId] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Filter1]
    GROUP BY [K1], [K2], [K3], [K4]
)  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=36
```

Comment: Isn't it the same actually? Also in your sql - you count the `playerId` but actually all it is is counting the number of records in the group - so it doesn't matter if it is 1 or player id

Comment: it's no different between count(1) and count(PlayerId). what do you want actually.

Comment: @EpoWilliam - Unless you want to know the distinct amount of playerId - is that the case?

Comment: SELECT count(1)  always return 1, no matter there is record or not.
And count(PlayerId) will only return the actual count of records.

Comment: Yes. count(1) always return 1 even though there is no record. But count(PlayerId) return 0 if there is no record.

Comment: @EpoWilliam - can you show some data? + results of database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only (but significant) difference between SQL `COUNT(field)` and `COUNT(1)` is that the former is excluding the `NULL` values, which when applied to the normally required field from the right side of a left outer join like in your case produces a different result when there are no matching records - the former returns 0 while the latter returns 1.

The "natural" LINQ equivalent would be `Count(field != null)`, but that unfortunately is translated to a quite different SQL by the current EF query provider. So in such cases I personally use the closer equivalent expression `Sum(field != null ? 1 : 0)` which produces a much better SQL.

In order to apply the above to your query, you'll need an access to `w` inside the grouping, so change

```
group new { p, s }
```

to

```
group new { p, s, w }
```

and then use

```
Trophy = grp.Sum(item => item.w != null ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. It return the correct answer. However, it is using SUM instead of COUNT, as you can see the SQL query generated as shown in the updated question.

Comment: Yes I know (and I think I mentioned why in the answer). This is the closest you can get from EF, there is no LINQ construct that let EF generate the exact SQL construct in the question.

Comment: Btw, `item.w != null` usually works good when you join by one field. In your case it produces redundant checks, `(int?)item.w.PlayerId != null` might be a better choice.